# .htaccess RewriteRule needed

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I am trying to trap old URL's of the form:

```
http://www.example.com/mpn_engine.php%3Ffamilyname%3Djiyalal+goswami%26menuopt%3D2%26submenuopt%3D1%26Search%3Dstuff
```

In my .htaccess file, with the help of various wise StackOverflowers as RegEx is alien to me, I have arranged to catch the PHP script 'mpn_engine.php' (both .php3 and newer .php copies) wherever it might be found (in any sub folder) and redirect visitors to the index page.

```
RewriteRule (^|/)mpn_engine\.php$ /index.html? [L,NC,R=301]
RewriteRule (^|/)mpn_engine\.php3$ /index.html? [L,NC,R=301]
```

The odd thing I am finding is that the above seems to work providing I seek after the php files exactly, or if I supply conventional parameters of the form:

```
http://www.example.com/lang/mpn_engine.php?x=fred
```

but as soon as I substitute a percent mark for the question mark, i.e. something like the following:

```
 http://www.example.com/lang/mpn_engine.php%x=fred
```

The Rewrite fails, & and I get unpredictable results, usualy a a 404 but occassionally a 'Bad Gateway'.

How can I rewrite this ReWriteRule to catch this .php file in any folder it might be looked for and with any trailing characters, including a percent sign, and redirect it gracefully to the index page?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm confused... Are you thinking that `% = ?` because it doesn't. `%3f` is the URL encoded (hexidecimal) value of a `?` and if you hadn't guessed `%3d` is the hexadecimal equivalent of `=`

Comment: Arbitrary `%` character in URL makes it an invalid URL and Apache will reject it even before mod_rewrite is invoked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question has a number of sub-questions:

1. If you want to "catch this .php file in any folder it might be
   looked for" then as long as your .htaccess file is in the root folder of your website (and not in a subfolder), then you are covered.
2. If you want to cover ANY trailing character, then you can make one of two changes to your rewrite rule:

   Remove the ending $:

   `RewriteRule (^|/)mpn_engine\.php /index.html? [L,NC,R=301]`

   or

   Add a wildcard after "php":

   `RewriteRule (^|/)mpn_engine\.php(.*)$ /index.html? [L,NC,R=301]`

   In the first case, if the $ present, this tells Apache to ONLY match if "php" is at the end of the URL. In the second case, this tells Apache to match if "php" is followed by zero or more of any other characters at the end of the URL. In either case, you do not need your second rewrite rule concerning "php3" -- either of these above will match for those instances as well.
3. The reason your first example with the "%" worked but subsequent attempts gave 404 errors is because the server translates "%3F" to "?", and "?" [has a special meaning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string) for web servers and is essentially ignored by your regex matcher -- thus the server acts as if "php" is the final part of the URL, and the rewrite succeeds.

Comment: Thank you so much Adam. Not only an informed reply but richly detailed too - a tacit education as well as information - both very much appreciated. Thank you very sincerely for helping steer me in the right direction on this. One very minor mystery remains. Is there any reason to choose 'no $' over the wildcard match? From what you say they are equivalent in this case?

Comment: No problem! For your purposes the two solutions are equivalent. Regex is a flexible language; thus it is common to see the same problem tackled in many different ways. The second solution is perhaps a little bit clearer to a novice as it is explicitly showing what to match through the very end of the URL. The first solution is probably more system-efficient because as soon as Apache matches "php" it can stop parsing your regex and execute the rewrite without needing to consider the rest of your URL.

Comment: Thank you again Adam. Very much appreciated.